# How do I modify my boot options in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

How do I modify the boot menu in Windows 8?  There's an entry that I want to remove for a "boot from VHD" option that no longer exists.

Comment: The BCDEDIT program seems to be what you're after, having trouble finding more info about it though, and whether it's different in windows 8.

Comment: http://henkhoogendoorn.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/guide-to-remove-windows-8-on-vhd.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the Windows buit in tool as well for this just type the `msconfig` in the run dialog box by pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

As shown in the image select the  boot entry which you want to delete and hit the delete button. For the current Windows in which you have boot this option will be unavailable.

Comment: How do I add an entry?

Comment: You don't asked in your question though so I didn't post for it. However @Hacktohell's answer is good for you with a GUI tool, but if you don't want to use third party tool then use **BCDEDIT** command of Windows. Check it out [here](http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-add-menu-items-to-the-selection-screen-in-windows-server-and-win7) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details. For run this command you have to launch the command line as admin.

Answer (score 12):

Removing a BCD entry is easy, you can use a tool called as [EasyBCD](http://www.howtogeek.com/75878/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-windows-8-from-your-dual-boot-setup/) to do the trick. After installing, all you have to do is remove it in the UI.

[image]

Hit the edit boot menu and remove Windows 8 bootloader.

[image]

Make Windows 7 bootloader as the default and you can boot using Windows 7 bootloader.