# while starting computer it is asking to boot into windows8

Tags: windows-8

when I start my computer it asks to boot into windows 8 or EasyRE, how to remove the EasyRE entry from bootloader and directly boot into windows 8 without being asked to select OS

Answer (score 0):

yeah, finally I solved my problem by deleting the EasyRE entry using the EasyBCD.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  For others who might have a similar problem, can you elaborate a little on your solution?  BTW, in two days you will be able to accept your own answer, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: [Duplicate of this post](http://superuser.com/questions/492151/how-do-i-modify-my-boot-options-in-windows-8/492158#492158)